# Fisher information of (weighted) sum of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, fisher-information

I am working on the Fisher information of a density $\rho$, defined as: $I(\rho) = \int \left\lVert \nabla_{x} \log \rho(x) \right\rVert^2 \rho(x) \mathrm{d} x$. The gradient is taken with respect to $x$. I couldn't find much resources on this integral. Can anyone suggest some notes for me?

I have two random variables with densities: $X \sim \rho_0(x), Y \sim \rho_1(y)$. I am studying the sum of these two variables: $Z = X + Y$ or $Z = aX + bY$ for parameters $a, b$. $Z$ will follow another density $p(z)$. What is the relationship between the Fisher information of these three variables? That is, what is the relationship between $I(p), I(\rho_0), I(\rho_1)$.

If it is possible to derive a property about $I(p)$, it would also be great.

Thank you.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Definition) might be a good resource. The notation you are using is a bit unclear. The derivative in the integral is usually taken with respect to a parameter of the distribution, but there doesn't seem to be any in your problem statement.

Comment: @angryavian, in this question, the parameter is known as the position parameter. In other words, the parameterized family consists of $\rho_\theta(x-\theta)$, $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. The definition of Fisher information for a parameterized family becomes the one stated here.

Comment: A paper worth looking at is https://isl.stanford.edu/~cover/papers/dembo_cover_thomas_91.pdf

Comment: Do you have more references that might be helpful?

Comment: @Deane Thanks very much, that clarification was super helpful!

Comment: You can also look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.04174.pdf and the papers it cites.

Comment: Is it correct to say that in general, there is an inequality $I(\sqrt{\lambda} X + \sqrt{1 - \lambda} Y) \leq \lambda I(X) + (1 - \lambda) I(Y)$? Do we have other relationships between these quantities? @Deane If you have pointers to other papers, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Moreover, would be great if you could recommend me papers about the relationship between Fisher information and entropy!